# Dynamic library to intercept oddsock hostname lookups

Tags: c, linked-list, networking, library, curl

Just for the fun of it, I decided I would try to create sort of an intermediate DNS system for the [oddsock SOCKS proxy](https://code.google.com/p/oddsock/). With this, the domain name extension .unet is statically resolved when requested. All of this is hooked into the oddsocks proxy system via inserting into the DYLD before libevent does. Tell me what you think.

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <event2/event.h>
#include <event2/buffer.h>
#include <event2/bufferevent.h>
#include <event2/dns.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
struct unetent { char name[64], ip[13]; };
struct lnode
{
    struct unetent data;
    struct lnode *next;
};
struct lnode * list_insert(struct lnode *list, char *name, char *ip);
int list_size(struct lnode *list);
struct unetent * list_get(struct lnode *list, int p);
struct lnode * list_getp(struct lnode *list, int p);
struct lnode * insert_from_file(struct lnode *list, FILE *f, int *code);
int (*original_bufferevent_socket_connect_hostname)(void *bev, void *evdns_base, int family, const char *hostname, int port) = NULL;
struct lnode *node_list = NULL;
time_t refresh_list_after = 0;
struct lnode * list_insert(struct lnode *list, char *name, char *ip)
{
    struct lnode *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct lnode)), *tmp = NULL;
    strcpy(ptr->data.name, name);
    strcpy(ptr->data.ip, ip);
    ptr->next = NULL;
    if (list == NULL) return ptr;
    for (tmp = list; tmp->next != NULL; tmp = tmp->next);
    tmp->next = ptr;
    return list;
}
int list_size(struct lnode *list)
{
    int i;
    struct lnode *tmp = list;
    for (i = 0; tmp != NULL; i++, tmp = tmp->next);
    return i;
}
struct unetent * list_get(struct lnode *list, int p)
{
    int i;
    struct lnode *tmp = list;
    for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
        tmp = tmp->next;
    return &tmp->data;
}
struct lnode * list_getp(struct lnode *list, int p)
{
    int i;
    struct lnode *tmp = list;
    if (p < 0) return NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
        tmp = tmp->next;
    return tmp;
}
struct lnode * insert_from_file(struct lnode *list, FILE *f, int *code)
{
    struct unetent tmp;
    if (code == NULL)
    code = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *code = fread(&tmp, sizeof(struct unetent), 1, f);
    if (*code > 0)
        return list_insert(list, tmp.name, tmp.ip);
    return list;
}
struct lnode * list_move_front(struct lnode *list, int nn)
{
    struct lnode * p = list_getp(list, nn - 1);
    struct lnode * c = list_getp(list, nn + 1);
    struct lnode * n = list_getp(list, nn + 0);
    if (nn == 0) return list;
    p->next = c;
    n->next = list;
    list = n;
    return list;
}
size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
{
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}
void update_list()
{
    time_t curr = time(NULL);
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    char *url = "http://97.85.72.250/out.dat";
    char *outfilename = "/tmp/undernet.dat";
    int readcode = 1;
    if (curr > refresh_list_after || node_list == NULL)
    {
        printf("\t[unet] Refreshing node cache...\n");
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl)
        {
            fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            fclose(fp);
        }
        fp = fopen(outfilename, "rb");
        while (readcode > 0)
            node_list = insert_from_file(node_list, fp, &readcode);
        refresh_list_after = time(NULL) + (3600); //refresh every minute
        unlink(outfilename);
    }
}
const char *lookup_ip_from_nodelist(const char *host)
{
    int i;
    const int end = list_size(node_list);
    struct unetent *tmp = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < end; i++)
    {
        tmp = list_get(node_list, i);
        if (strcmp(tmp->name, host) == 0)
        {
            node_list = list_move_front(node_list, i);
            return (const char *)tmp->ip;
        }
    }
    return (const char *)host;
}
char isunet(const char *name)
{
    const char *endurit = strstr(name, "/");
    const char *enduri = endurit ? endurit : name + strlen(name);
    return (strstr(name, ".unet") == enduri - strlen(".unet"));
}
const char *undernet_translate_URI(const char *name)
{
    if (isunet(name))
    {
        update_list();
        return lookup_ip_from_nodelist(name);
    }
    return name;
}
int bufferevent_socket_connect_hostname(struct bufferevent *bev, struct evdns_base *evdns_base, int family, const char *hostname, int port)
{
    if (original_bufferevent_socket_connect_hostname == NULL)
        original_bufferevent_socket_connect_hostname = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "bufferevent_socket_connect_hostname");
    return original_bufferevent_socket_connect_hostname(bev, evdns_base, family, undernet_translate_URI(hostname), port);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Concept

There are architecturally cleaner ways to achieve a similar result.

- Configure the machine on which `oddsock` is running to point to your own proxying nameserver, such as [`dnsmasq`](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html).  That nameserver resolves hostnames against a local database, and falls back to an upstream DNS server if not found.
- If you don't want to affect the name resolution configuration for any other processes running on the same machine as `oddsock`, then monkey-patching `oddsock` is a reasonable hack.  However, instead of overriding `bufferevent_socket_connect_hostname()`, you should probably create a hook for [`evdns_base_new()`](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-2.0/doxygen/html/dns_8h.html#a01e7ab67e97b46dc4962bbc29d0d0604) instead.  With that hook, you could…

  - Insert a call to [`evdns_base_nameserver_ip_add()`](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-2.0/doxygen/html/dns_8h.html#a5d90b3ed3156d5c1884a651e87e66e17) to tell `oddsock` to use the aforementioned proxying nameserver, or
  - Fetch the mappings from `http://97.85.72.250/out.dat` into a temporary file, then insert a call to [`evdns_base_load_hosts()`](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-2.0/doxygen/html/dns_8h.html#af525d88e4075b04472db44e412cd6922) to load them all.  It might be a good idea to add an `alarm(2)` and `SIGALRM` handler that reloads the host definitions.

These solutions don't require any meddling after the initial setup hook.  Almost all of your code disappears.

#### Data structure

Linked lists [generally](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/5/22/strategy-stop-using-linked-lists.html) [suck](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo).  There are few situations where they shine, and this is certainly not one of them.

The number of entries is known in advance: it's the number of bytes in `out.dat` divided by `sizeof struct unetent`.  You could just `malloc()` an array.

The only reason you have code to manipulate the list at all is to put the most recently used entries in front for performance.  If you had used a hashtable instead, then everything would have been O(1), and you wouldn't be rearranging entries needlessly.

#### Performance

Since `update_list()` is called from within `undernet_translate_URI()`, the refreshing of the host definitions happens synchronously.  As a result, once a minute, a request would take longer than normal.

`list_move_front()` calls `list_getp(list, nn + …)` three times.  Each call takes O(*nn*) time.  But `c` is just `n->next`.  Usually, `n` is `p->next` (as long as `n` is not the head node).

#### Bugs

Writing to a hard-coded temporary file (`/tmp/undernet.dat`) is a security risk.  Use `mkstemp()` or `tmpfile()` or [`open(…, O_TMPFILE)` in Linux for Workgroups](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.11#head-8be09d59438b31c2a724547838f234cb33c40357).

`insert_from_file()` would leak memory if `code` is `NULL`.  I don't recommend `malloc()` and `free()` at all in that situation, though.  It would be more idiomatic C to return the status code, and manipulate `list` by reference.  Better yet, incorporate the `while` loop so that one function loads the entire file.  (By the way, `while (readcode > 0)` would be better as a do-while loop.)

#### Summary

Interesting idea.  However, it could be done with a cleaner architecture, which would eliminate most of the code.  Furthermore, linked list is a poor choice of data structure, and it's not worth optimizing that.

Comment: I actually considered scrapping the remote dl and going for straight sql entries. I dont know if it was a bad choice to decide to keep local (thank you for the hash table idea, completely forgot that one) or if i should go full remote.

Comment: SQL? No. Be practical: think like a system administrator, not a programmer. Strive for a solution that involves configuration only, no code, and standard protocols. That means setting up a DNS server — `dnsmasq` is your best bet, I think.

Comment: And your suggestion is that I make the update_list work async? Or that I should time it to run out of cycle, when it isnt being depended on? Also: my only concern with not using something like SQL is that the list could potentially be very large. I would like to steer away from third party servers as I do this as a learning experience, and just some fun.

Comment: No, my suggestion is to use a nameserver for name resolution, because that is precisely what DNS is for. The UDP-based protocol is efficient, the DNS server will have code that is fast, results will be authoritative and management will be centralized. Configure `oddsock` to use a nameserver that resolves entries in the .unet zone and **don't write _any_ code.** If you'd like, follow-up on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595) or ask [su] about how to accomplish this (possibly [sf], but this doesn't seem like a kind of question that a professional sysadmin would ask).

Answer (score 8):

- I'd recommend staying consistent with curly brace usage for conditionals.  It can help with readability and also ease maintainability if you end up needing to add additional lines.

  ```
  if (someCondition)
  {
      // do something...
      // can still do something else...
  }
  ```

  However, it's okay to leave them out if you have a single-line conditional that you *know* will never require more than one line:

  ```
  if (someConditional) return something;
  ```
- Your loop counters should be declared right before the loop statement as opposed to the start of the function (before the other variables).  Doing so will keep a minimum scope on the counter, and everything will be in one place should the loop ever need to be removed.
- `write_data()` doesn't need two lines:

  > ```
  > size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
  > {
  >     size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
  >     return written;
  > }
  > ```

  It can just have one line

  ```
  size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
  {
      return fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
  }
  ```

  If the return value of `fwrite()` will just be returned right away, then another variable isn't needed.  The name also doesn't add much to what is already known about the function.

Comment: sorry. My program for formatting to stackexchange sites looks for braces to do tabbing when it reformats. Since it was missing the brace, it got untabbed. I will correct those.

Comment: should be good now

Comment: @phyrrus9: I've edited my answer to address something similar instead.  Since this wasn't intentional, I'll let it slide.  For future reference, please don't make corrections on the original code from answers, even if it's a simple fix.

Comment: I agree with that, and most of my code does follow that syntax. If I don't have a reason to put it all on one line, then it has curly braces. For this, however, this is the debugging code, and therefore does not include final formatting and is intended to be as less line-wastey as possible

Comment: @phyrrus9: That could be something to state for future questions.  We are allowed to review whatever is given to us (assuming there's nothing else to request clarification for), not just specific requests.

Comment: I was looking for everything. I appreciate that comment, in future posts I will ensure to include them if stated that it makes it easier to read. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This review addresses only list management.

**naming**

I'd prefer `list_get_data` and `list_get_node` over `list_get` and `list_getp`.
`list_insert` is in fact `list_append`, and shall return `ptr` (the caller already knows what `list` is, while `ptr` carries valuable information, as we shall see).

**overall code organization**

I don't like `node_list` being global. Globals are bad.

`list_move_front`, `list_get`, `list_getp` need null pointer checking.

A need to access a list by index raise suspicions (see below).

**efficiency**

For lists your program manages it is probably not relevant. Nevertheless, `insert_from_file` exhibits a quadratic complexity. Should `list_insert` return a pointer to a newly created node, the complexity would become linear.

**suggested improvements**

`list_move_front` doesn't need to traverse the list 3 times, as it does. It is enough to do it once.

Notice that lists with a simple payload (such as in your case - a single pointer) are subject to a very simple node extraction: you don't need to know the previous one (see below).

The way `list_move_front` is called adds two more traversals (one explicit, and one due to `list_size()`).

I'd suggest having

```
struct lnode * list_find(struct lnode * head, const char * name)
    while (head != NULL)
        if (strcmp(head->name, name)) break;
        else head = head->next;
    return head;
}
```

Now `lookup_ip_from_nodelist` can be rewritten as

```
struct lnode * node = list_find(node_list, hostname);
if (node == NULL) return hostname;
node_list = detach_node(node);
return node->ip;
```

`detach_node` implements the trick mentioned above (a seemingly special case of `node->next` being NULL is addressed by having a sentinel node):

```
struct lnode * detach_node(struct lnode * node)
{
    struct lnode * next = node->next;
    node_next = next->next;
    char * ip = node->ip;
    node->ip = next->ip;
    next->ip = tmp;
    return next;
}
```

Notice that all index-based helpers (`list_size`, `list_get`, `list_getp`) are eliminated.